# If any one familiar with Andrew ng's Planer data classification with one hidden layer

Tags: pandas, deep-learning

How the value of X_assess dimension will be (2,3) in the below code, how did they get that..Am trying with my problem and got stuck over there

```
def forward_propagation_test_case():
    np.random.seed(1)
    X_assess = np.random.randn(2, 3)
    b1 = np.random.randn(4,1)
    b2 = np.array([[ -1.3]])

    parameters = {'W1': np.array([[-0.00416758, -0.00056267],
    [-0.02136196,  0.01640271],
    [-0.01793436, -0.00841747],
    [ 0.00502881, -0.01245288]]),
   'W2': np.array([[-0.01057952, -0.00909008,  0.00551454,  0.02292208]]),
   'b1': b1,
   'b2': b2}

   return X_assess, parameters
```